# Unpivot columns based on select

Tags: sql-server-2008, unpivot

It is possible to do Unpivot operation, where column names are done via select, without using dynamic SQL ?

I tried this, but it fails.

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Report]
UNPIVOT
(
  Value
  FOR WeekName IN 
  (
      SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns c
      WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'Report'
      AND ORDINAL_POSITION > 1
      ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
  )
) u
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UNPIVOT is not the best way to unpivot a table, CROSS APPLY with VALUES is a far better method.

Sorry, but I don't think you can get away from Dynamic SQL for this one.

This code will dynamically unpivot an entire table.

```
DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(255) = 'Employee'
DECLARE @schemaname  VARCHAR(255) = 'HumanResources'
DECLARE @qrystr NVARCHAR(4000) = ''

;with cte
    AS
    (
    SELECT
        c.column_id
        ,c.name
    FROM
        sys.objects o 
            INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
                ON
                o.object_id = c.object_id
    WHERE
        o.name = @tablename
        AND
        SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) = @schemaname
    )
SELECT
@qrystr = 
'SELECT A.[' + (SELECT name FROM cte WHERE column_id = 1) + '] 
    ,C.Name
    ,C.Val
FROM
    [' + @schemaname + '].[' + @tablename + '] A

    CROSS APPLY (VALUES ' +
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + '(CAST(['+name + '] AS VARCHAR(255)),''' + name + ''')' FROM cte WHERE column_id > 1 ORDER BY column_id FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
    + ' ) C(Val,Name)'

EXEC (@qrystr)
```